# Centos 7 stopped detecting all RAM on system?

Tags: centos, memory, ram

After months of working fine, the BIOS for my Centos 7 installation suddenly maps the wrong amount of memory to the kernel. I have 8 GB of RAM installed and the SO only maps 3.2 GB of RAM. I can't understand why.

This is all the info that I believe to be of concern, but if you need something more please let me know.

About the hardware:

```
CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
Motherboard: GA-MA780G-UD3H
Rare Hardware: MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon]
```

**dmesg | grep -i mem**

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e801: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e801: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000cdecffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xcff00000-0xffffffff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f57c0-0x000f57cf] mapped at [fffffffffd2007c0]
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000098000] 98000 size 24576
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x3529f000-0x36947fff]
[    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000cdecffff]
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0xcdeae000-0xcdecffff]
[    0.000000] crashkernel: memory value expected
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000cdecffff]
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000cdecffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x00000000cdecffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 13116 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0xcded0000-0xffffffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.007556] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
[    0.028268] Fam 10h mmconf [mem 0xe0000000-0xe00fffff]
[    0.028268] bus: 00 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.028268] bus: 00 [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff]
[    0.028268] bus: 00 [mem 0xe0600000-0xffffffff]
[    0.028268] bus: 00 [mem 0xe0100000-0xe05fffff]
[    0.028268] bus: 00 [mem 0x230000000-0xfcffffffff]
[    0.028268] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
[    0.038526] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
[    0.039286] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
[    0.046039] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.046040] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.046042] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xd0000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    0.046769] pci 0000:00:11.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0xfe02f000-0xfe02f3ff]
[    0.046916] pci 0000:00:12.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe02e000-0xfe02efff]
[    0.047077] pci 0000:00:12.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe02d000-0xfe02dfff]
[    0.047240] pci 0000:00:12.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe02c000-0xfe02c0ff]
[    0.047432] pci 0000:00:13.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe02b000-0xfe02bfff]
[    0.047588] pci 0000:00:13.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe02a000-0xfe02afff]
[    0.047749] pci 0000:00:13.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe029000-0xfe0290ff]
[    0.048567] pci 0000:00:14.5: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe028000-0xfe028fff]
[    0.049170] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.049179] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfd7e0000-0xfd7effff 64bit]
[    0.049197] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.049293] pci 0000:01:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfd7fc000-0xfd7fffff 64bit]
[    0.052017] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.052020] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.052087] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xfdffc000-0xfdffffff 64bit]
[    0.052098] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xfdf80000-0xfdfbffff 64bit]
[    0.052112] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.055016] pci 0000:00:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdf00000-0xfdffffff]
[    0.055019] pci 0000:00:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.055100] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfddff000-0xfddfffff 64bit]
[    0.055112] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xfdcfc000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.058021] pci 0000:00:09.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.058024] pci 0000:00:09.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.058104] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfdaff000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.058116] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xfdae0000-0xfdaeffff 64bit pref]
[    0.058125] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
[    0.061019] pci 0000:00:0a.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.061022] pci 0000:00:0a.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.061100] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff]
[    0.061104] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff pref]
[    0.061109] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    0.061111] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    0.061112] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xfebfffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    0.062580] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.071632] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.071634] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xcded0000-0xcfffffff]
[    0.089630] pnp 00:01: disabling [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff window] because it overlaps 0000:01:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.089635] pnp 00:01: disabling [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff window disabled] because it overlaps 0000:02:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0001ffff pref]
[    0.089640] pnp 00:01: disabling [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff window disabled] because it overlaps 0000:04:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
[    0.089699] system 00:01: [mem 0xfee00400-0xfee00fff window] has been reserved
[    0.090378] system 00:03: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
[    0.090592] system 00:04: [mem 0x000d7c00-0x000d7fff] has been reserved
[    0.090595] system 00:04: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000f7fff] could not be reserved
[    0.090597] system 00:04: [mem 0x000f8000-0x000fbfff] could not be reserved
[    0.090598] system 00:04: [mem 0x000fc000-0x000fffff] could not be reserved
[    0.090600] system 00:04: [mem 0xcfee0000-0xcfefffff] could not be reserved
[    0.090602] system 00:04: [mem 0xffff0000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
[    0.090603] system 00:04: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
[    0.090605] system 00:04: [mem 0x00100000-0xcfedffff] could not be reserved
[    0.090607] system 00:04: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] could not be reserved
[    0.090609] system 00:04: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] could not be reserved
[    0.090610] system 00:04: [mem 0xfff80000-0xfffeffff] has been reserved
[    0.097979] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd71ffff pref]
[    0.097988] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.097990] pci 0000:00:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.097994] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfdf00000-0xfdf1ffff pref]
[    0.098000] pci 0000:00:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdf00000-0xfdffffff]
[    0.098009] pci 0000:00:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098017] pci 0000:00:09.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.098019] pci 0000:00:09.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098023] pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdb0ffff pref]
[    0.098028] pci 0000:00:0a.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.098030] pci 0000:00:0a.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098041] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff]
[    0.098044] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff pref]
[    0.098056] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.098057] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.098059] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0xd0000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    0.098062] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xfd700000-0xfd7fffff]
[    0.098063] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098067] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xfdf00000-0xfdffffff]
[    0.098068] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098071] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.098073] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098075] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.098077] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.098080] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff]
[    0.098082] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff pref]
[    0.098086] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.098087] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.098089] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 8 [mem 0xd0000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    0.440156] pci 0000:01:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.889247] Freeing initrd memory: 23204K
[    1.415893] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    1.416846] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: irq 17, io mem 0xfe02c000
[    1.423652] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: irq 19, io mem 0xfe029000
[    1.430547] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02e000
[    1.486520] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.1: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02d000
[    1.542513] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02b000
[    1.598498] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.1: irq 18, io mem 0xfe02a000
[    1.654502] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: irq 18, io mem 0xfe028000
[    1.724405] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2232K
[    1.724676] Freeing unused kernel memory: 132K
[    1.726622] Freeing unused kernel memory: 544K
[    2.019715] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff], which spans more than pnp 00:04 [mem 0x000d7c00-0x000d7fff]
[    2.020483] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1651458 kiB
[    2.020515] [drm] radeon: 256M of VRAM memory ready
[    2.020516] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux <host> 4.14.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 12 20:21:04 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lshw -short | grep 'System Memory'**

```
/0/29                           memory      8GiB System Memory
```

**free -m**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3225         155          95           8        2974        2838
Swap:          8191           0        8191
```

**lshw -c memory**

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Award Software International, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F5
       date: 10/08/2009
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 960KiB
       capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: Internal Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: External Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: Internal Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 29
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: None
          vendor: None
          physical id: 0
          serial: None
          slot: A0
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: None
          vendor: None
          physical id: 1
          serial: None
          slot: A1
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: None
          vendor: None
          physical id: 2
          serial: None
          slot: A2
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: None
          vendor: None
          physical id: 3
          serial: None
          slot: A3
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
```

**cat /proc/meminfo | grep Direct**

```
DirectMap4k:       95040 kB
DirectMap2M:     2230272 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

Comment: Please add to the question: `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Direct`

Comment: Errr... did you change any BIOS settings? Maybe memory remapping, memory hole, etc. ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added ;)

Comment: 4GB indeed...strange.

Comment: @derobert no, and I tried to find the options and without any success. I also tried to remove one module, start - stop, add it again without any change.

Comment: do a memtest....

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I did it too but only detects the same 3.2GB so the final test end successfully.

Comment: I agree with @RuiFRibeiro, but different versions of `memtest` support different amounts of memory. For 8GB you need 5 version. Before the memory test, you need to remove all modules and wipe the contacts with an eraser and degrease with alcohol.

Comment: @Alex_Krug I use the version 5, but I'll remove as you said with wipe included and retest everything. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alex_Krug I did what you said, I cleaned them and did the Memtest v5.01 and again, test without errors but only 3294MB of RAM.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro as far as I can see, I think the problem is my bios is not reporting with the e820 function, only with the e801 and it reports the 3294MB exactly. I tried to install a new version of the bios but the result it's still the same.

Comment: the bios is not to blame. What is the memory configuration? How many slots are occupied? What modules? Great suspicions of slots in the motherboard. Try to take out the modules, test the modules separately, in different slots. In short, try any combination to identify the faulty slot or module. Yes, and for a reminder, no one OS should be loaded when testing the memory.

Comment: @Alex_Krug I tested it with the memtest so no OS is loaded I tried one module of memory on each slot, but I didn't try the 4 slots with the four modules (the 16 combinations), but i'll try that. About the memory configuration which is important it's that it isn't new (and it worked with the full 8GB). I has been unchanged for a year and it's 4 slots with 2GB on each one. Bought in a single package for maximum compatibility.